# In pine script, is the line 'WTCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0' a condition statement?

Tags: conditional-statements, pine-script

Can you tell me if this line in Pine script is a condition statement please ? What does it do ?

WTCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

It is a boolean operation. `WTCrossUp` will be assignend either `true` or `false`.

ie

if `wt2 - wt1` is `less than or equal to zero` then `WTCrossUp` will be `true`